# Average number of people per name?

Tags: census-records, surnames

Are there statistics of "name ambiguity?

For example, how many people share the same full name on average?

This would be particularily interesting per country.

Answer (score 8):

Although it may seem otherwise when researching a family with a common name in a limited area, **Anglo-Saxon full names (first and last) are surprisingly unique.**  It's statistically quite uncommon for two full names to be the same.

#### US Death Data

The Social Security Death Index (Death Master File) is a file of about 88 million people, a subset of those who have died in the United States in the past 70 or so years (with most of the names in the later years).

Using that data (for the 2010-11-17 edition), I've sorted it by first and last name (ignoring middle initials or names, as they're not consistently reported). There are 31,425,850 different unique names for the 87,873,196 people listed.

Here are most common full names (first 50 shown, with the number of times they occur):

`20944 JAMES SMITH
  20590 WILLIAM SMITH
  18845 MARY SMITH
  17938 JOHN SMITH
  16307 ROBERT SMITH
  13540 JAMES WILLIAMS
  13432 JAMES JOHNSON
  12980 WILLIAM JOHNSON
  12807 CHARLES SMITH
  12625 JAMES BROWN
  12366 JOHN JOHNSON
  12296 MARY JOHNSON
  12125 JOHN WILLIAMS
  11957 WILLIAM BROWN
  11873 ROBERT JOHNSON
  11790 WILLIAM JONES
  10915 GEORGE SMITH
  10707 MARY WILLIAMS
  10690 JAMES JONES
  10514 MARY BROWN
  10323 JOHN MILLER
  10022 MARY JONES
   9989 WILLIAM MILLER
   9869 JOHN JONES
   9768 ROBERT WILLIAMS
   9700 JOHN BROWN
   9604 ROBERT JONES
   9560 JAMES DAVIS
   9416 ROBERT BROWN
   9069 WILLIAM DAVIS
   8906 MARY MILLER
   8671 JOHN DAVIS
   8201 ROBERT MILLER
   8083 CHARLES JOHNSON
   8037 MARY DAVIS
   7986 JAMES WILSON
   7506 JAMES MILLER
   7285 HELEN SMITH
   7243 JAMES MOORE
   7116 JAMES TAYLOR
   7103 CHARLES BROWN
   7095 JOHN ANDERSON
   7017 WILLIAM WILSON
   7015 MARGARET SMITH
   6989 JOHN WILSON
   6983 CHARLES MILLER
   6956 GEORGE JOHNSON
   6849 CHARLES WILLIAMS
   6756 DOROTHY SMITH
   6739 WILLIAM TAYLOR`

Even the most common name, James Smith, only occurs 20,944 times (out of 87,873,196) - so 0.02%, or 1 in 4200 people have that name.  And it rapidly tails off - there are only 2,395 names that occur more than 1,000 times, totalling 4,848,744 people (and this is ignoring middle names, which would make them more unique).

The mode (most commonly occurring frequency) is 1 with 23,524,403, in other words **there's a more than 1 in 4 chance any particular full name only occurs once**.  There's only a 1 in 18 chance that a name is a name that occurs more than 1,000 times. The mean number of times each name occurs is 2.8, the standard deviation is 26.5.

Since this is historical data, based on people dying decades ago (so born many more decades ago), it won't reflect the current name frequencies in the US.

#### US White Pages and Facebook

An article last year used full name frequencies from the recent US White Pages (so still biased, towards older landline users).  That has many more Hispanic names, and a strange dearth of John Smiths: [Why Aren’t There More John Smiths in the U.S.?](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/slate_labs/2013/11/john_smith_why_don_t_more_americans_have_this_most_common_name.html)

A 2009 report of Facebook names found instead there were too many Jane Smiths (possibly as fake names): [Most Common First, Last, and Full Names on Facebook](https://www.rapleaf.com/2009/06/22/rapleaf-study-most-common-first-last-and-full-names-on-facebook/)

#### Global Names

As you mentioned, it would be nice to have the uniqueness of names by country (and culture).  I'm not aware of any source for this, since it's hard to get a full name list (even historical) for most countries, or censuses. In most countries, there are almost no bulk downloads possible for genealogy or name data (other than separate tables of first and last name ranks).

However, a larger [Facebook name list](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2010/return-of-the-facebook-snatchers) from October 2010 (170,879,859 names) is moderately global and has 100,128,460 different full "real" names (some of these names will be fiction and intentionally original).  The following names make the top 50. Note how they occur even less times, despite the larger sample, because there's a wider variety of names.  It's heavily biased towards male names, perhaps because female users are less likely to complete their real names.

`17204 john smith
   7440 david smith
   7200 michael smith
   6784 chris smith
   6371 mike smith
   6149 arun kumar
   5980 james smith
   5939 amit kumar
   5926 imran khan
   5861 jason smith
   5374 chris johnson
   5294 jessica smith
   5231 chris brown
   5210 mike jones
   5092 michael johnson
   5084 mark smith
   5039 sarah smith
   4953 anil kumar
   4877 manoj kumar
   4875 praveen kumar
   4771 ashley smith
   4749 vijay kumar
   4693 kevin smith
   4646 david johnson
   4587 chris jones
   4538 sunil kumar
   4515 ryan smith
   4493 robert smith
   4462 david jones
   4452 brian smith
   4367 jennifer smith
   4343 ahmed ali
   4316 steve smith
   4315 rajesh kumar
   4291 rahul sharma
   4230 paul smith
   4213 michael williams
   4201 ravi kumar
   4155 michael brown
   4153 raj kumar
   4141 david brown
   4031 amanda smith
   3965 lisa smith
   3946 ali khan
   3936 matt smith
   3921 david williams
   3920 chris williams
   3826 john williams
   3757 andrew smith
   3742 adam smith`

Here the mode is 1 with 86,585,871 - so **there's a better than 1 in 2 chance any particular real full name on Facebook is unique**. The mean is 1.7, standard deviation is 10.4.

It's unclear why some names in the 2009 Facebook report, like Jane Smith and Juan Carlos, hardly appear in the 2010 list.  Both lists are just samples, so there must be something very different about the way they were obtained (and which shows that all such rankings should be considered just estimates based on available data).

### Other Cultures

Even that Facebook data is hardly global - strong on western countries, and south Asia, but it very poorly represents names from East Asia, Africa, and South America (one reason: that list is limited to names which start with a latin character set character).

There are some countries where names are nearly unique (like [Thailand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_name)).  Many other cultures have a shortage of "last" names (family names), sometimes because of the way they were introduced.  This applies especially to China, [Korea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_name) and parts of Scandinavia.  There are also countries, like Iceland and Korea (among others), which require first names to be from an approved list, limiting the variety of names available.

Comment: What a wonderful answer, Rob! Can I just point out that you have achieved an example of the kind of [statistical genealogy](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3351/394) I was thinking of in an earlier question. I wonder if the distributions of first names were independent of surnames or vice versa. Could be a good question for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), the statistics StackExchange.

Comment: @verbeia - at a first glance at the SSDI data above, James is the most common male first name for almost all these top surnames, and Mary the most common female name. One exception is Miller, where John wins. I'd guess this is because many of the Millers were originally Muellers, from Germany. So the distribution of first name by surname will very by the ethnic origins of that name (it becomes even more obvious of course with Hispanic names). And it'll also vary by decade of birth, as names go out of fashion (such as Robert, in recent decades).

Answer (score 2):

UCL did some work on the distribution of surnames in the UK which is accessible via the [PublicProfiler](http://www.publicprofiler.org/index.php?p=familyname) website. I'm not aware of anything that looks at the combination of forenames and surnames.